# jQuery UI sortable dynamic containment issue

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am building a appointment scheduler using jQuery UI sortable where the appointments are draggable, droppable and sortable, this is nearly complete save for one issue that I cannot get my head around concerning sortable option 'containment'.

To try and give a brief overview, to create the behavior I wanted I created the scheduler using two combined sortables, one acting as a 'canvas' - an area where we can drag the appointments around and a sortable so we can drag appointments into blocks of other appointments within the canvas. I flirted with combining draggable and sortable but this option was not giving me quite the desired behavior.

Now, part of the scheduler is the ability to create a new line (day) which in turn expands the canvas area, this (to look at) works fine with extra logic I've added, new line appears etc but the containment size (set to the canvas area) will not update 'on the fly' and therefore there's an area of the canvas (bottom - the size of the new day) which I can not drag over. Only when I drop the appointment onto a new line does the containment area update with the new height and I can then drag an appointment into the bottom area.

My question is, is this default sortable containment behavior - that the containment area size will/can only update upon stop/update, or is there a way to force an update to containment size while dragging.

I have searched extensively for an answer on this but cannot find anything on this particular topic, any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't have a solution (yet, I found your post whilst looking for a solution)...

But, I did find this, http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4781

Looks like it's a known bug, and they're indicating it's not going to be fixed for another version or so. They indicate a patch there, but I haven't tried it yet. Good luck!

EDIT: I did actually apply this patch in a test environment, and it looks like it works; in my particular case it turned out that the parent was not actually changing size, so it didn't help me- thought I'd report back though.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, I haven't used SO before. I didn't notice an option to comment at the time I posted my, uh, comment : )

Comment: where/how in the JS file is this patch applied?